# Error: Could not identify the intended function with name 'swapExactTokensForTokens'

Tags: python-3.x, blockchain

I'm trying to swap tokens using `swapExactTokensForTokens()` (Pancakeswap Router function), web3 imported in Python. Here's my code and error below. Please be specific in your answers, as I'm a newbie to coding.

```
tokenToSpend=$BUSD, tokenToBuy=$CAKE
```

Code:

```
#Calculate minimum amount of tokens to receive

receive = contract.functions.getAmountsOut(amount, [tokenToSpend, tokenToBuy]).call()
minReceived = receive[1] * (9/10)                                                       
receiveReadable = web3.fromWei(minReceived,'ether')                       
print("Minimum tokens to recieve:", str(receiveReadable))

#Trade execution:

pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(minReceived, [tokenToSpend,tokenToBuy], sender_address, (int(time.time()) + 1000000)).buildTransaction({   
            'from': sender_address,
            'value': web3.toWei(amount,'ether'), 
            'gasPrice': web3.toWei('5','gwei'),
            'nonce': nonce,
            })
```

Here's the error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Owner/Documents/BlockchainPy/MyCodes/BuyPancake.py", line 64, in <module>
    pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(minReceived, [spend,tokenToBuy], sender_address, (int(time.time()) + 1000000)).buildTransaction({

  File "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\BlockchainPy\lib\site-packages\web3\contract.py",
line 876, in __call__
    clone._set_function_info()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\BlockchainPy\lib\site-packages\web3\contract.py",
line 881, in _set_function_info
    self.abi = find_matching_fn_abi(
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\BlockchainPy\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\contracts.py", line 163, in find_matching_fn_abi
    raise ValidationError(message)
web3.exceptions.ValidationError:
Could not identify the intended function with name `swapExactTokensForTokens`, positional argument(s) of type `(<class 'float'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'int'>)` and keyword argument(s) of type `{}`.
Found 1 function(s) with the name `swapExactTokensForTokens`: ['swapExactTokensForTokens(uint256,uint256,address[],address,uint256)']
Function invocation failed due to improper number of arguments.
```

Comment: Could the error message possibly be more clear?  You are passing 4 arguments and the function requires 5.  https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contracts/router02/

Comment: Looks like you got to the *Could not identify* line and just stopped reading. If you also read the two lines that follow it, they tell you **exactly** what the problem is and what's causing it. There's a reason they put those extra two lines of text in there, but they only work if someone actually reads them.

Comment: @Ken White Of course I read through it. How else would I know that I have an issue? I just didn't know what arguments I was missing. Tim Roberts Thanks for your helpful response. The documentation was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try re-copy-and-pasting your Factory or Router ABIs... It seems I found and replaced "MyVariableName" from "WBNB" (or "WETH") in the mentioned ABIs. Got rid of that error after a bit of looking around

Answer (score 0):

After minReceived you need to supply minAmountOut which is basically slippage. Try 0, that will essentially match the best price and it should work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).